# If new comment posted in custom post - send notification to custom email from custom field

Tags: comments, email, notifications, wp-mail

I have custom post type "Art masters". 
Each post is master's profile.

In their profiles isset custom fiels name "master_email".
I need to send for master email notification every time if new comment is posted.

How i can call post new comment function for use wp_mail? Thank you for help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try something like this in your functions.php

```
function send_comment_email_notification( $comment_ID, $commentdata ) {
    $comment = get_comment( $comment_id );
    $postid = $comment->comment_post_ID;
    $master_email = get_post_meta( $postid, 'master_email', true);
    if( isset( $master_email ) && is_email( $master_email ) ) {
        $message = 'New comment on <a href="' . get_permalink( $postid ) . '">' .  get_the_title( $postid ) . '</a>';
        add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', create_function( '', 'return "text/html";' ) );
        wp_mail( $master_email, 'New Comment', $message );
    }
}
add_action( 'comment_post', 'send_comment_email_notification', 11, 2 );
```

Comment: That's OK but 2 things need to be pointed out: 1. `get_comment( $comment_id )` should be `get_comment( $comment_ID )` 2. in order for this function to work, post meta (custom field) should have **name** - **value** pair declared: **master_email** - **somebody@somedomain.com**

Comment: Is there a way to send the mail only on 0 and 1 comments (not for spam comments)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Example:`helenyhou@example.com`

```
add_filter('wp_mail_from','yoursite_wp_mail_from'); 

function yoursite_wp_mail_from($content_type) {
   return 'helenyhou@example.com'; 
} 

add_filter('wp_mail_from_name','yoursite_wp_mail_from_name'); 

function yoursite_wp_mail_from_name($name) {
   return 'Helen Hou-Sandi'; 
}
```